# Croppie JS - Only working randomly on gallery of photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid of photos and I'm using croppie to crop photos. When you click a photo, it launches a bootstrap modal, and initializes a new croppie in the modal and binds that image. It only seems to be working for a couple pictures before it stops working. Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var uploadCrop;

    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      uploadCrop = $('#uploadCrop').croppie({
          viewport: {
              width: 200,
              height: 200
          },
          boundary: {
              width: 300,
              height: 300
          }
      });
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
      var profile = button.data('image') 

      uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
          url: profile
      });

      uploadCrop.croppie('setZoom', 1.5)
    })

    $('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) {
      uploadCrop.croppie('destroy')
    })

  });
```

I've noticed that the image is binding to the new croppie, but it is set to `opacity:0` and the `cr-slider` is not set or where it should be.

Comment: Did you try on `shown` instead of `show`?

Comment: @makshh That actually makes sense. I feel dumb for that. That worked.